# zoompan filter creates shaky image?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-editing

I try to perform a basic zoompan with FFmpeg. I have an input list image (.jpg 400x300) and i create slice image video (.mp4 400*300) from it, with a zoom each image. This is my command:

```css
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image01.jpg -loop 1 -i image02.jpg -loop 1 -i image03.jpg  -filter_complex "
 [0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=400 ,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=400*300,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; 
 [1:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=400*300,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; 
 [2:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5,scale=400*300,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; 
 [v0][v1][v2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0, format=yuv420p[v]" -c:v libx264 -map "[v]"  output_no_audio.mp4
```

Everything works...but the zoom is not looking okay. It is going zig-zag (the first image scale from center, remaining part is scale default)

i've already consulted this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499930/ffmpeg-zoom-not-smooth-centered-but-zigzag). But it inapplicable to this situation.

Does anyone know how to make it zoom smooth and explain how to calculate ?

thank in advance !